# Simulate modems and leased line over ethernet

Tags: serial, ethernet, modem

I am using a leased line with two modems on the edges. Those modems receive x.21 protocol from db25 connector on their back and transmit to each other over the leased line. 
For some pairs of leased lines technology made easier to have a wireless point to point connection over wifi. So I am wondering if there is any kind of equipment that can emulate the modems over the Ethernet protocol.
I made a research online and there are many "serial server devices" as they call them...
Do you thing this kind of equipment is what I need?

Answer (score 1):

You can try X.25 over TCP/IP over Ethernet.

For example, [Cicso](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/wan/x25-protocols/9363-x25-over-tcpip.html) and [Wanware](http://www.wanware.com/products_legacynetwork.html) provides some solutions.

Also, search in Google for something like "X.25 over TCP/IP modem" or "serial tunneling over TCP/IP" yourself.

Good luck.

Comment: Do you thing these devices can do the job? http://www.ebay.com/itm/221666814434?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT